# SymPy vector substraction not doing what expected

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have this code in which I try to do a Vector calculation, but the code does not do what would be mathematically expected:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D

N = CoordSys3D('N')
t = sp.symbols('t')

r = sp.symbols('r')
w = sp.symbols('w')
o = sp.symbols('o')


x = sp.Function('x')(t)
y = sp.Function('y')(t)
z = sp.Function('z')(t)

p = x*N.i + y*N.j + z*N.k

q = r*(p.dot(N.i)*sp.cos(w*t)+p.dot(N.j)*sp.sin(w*t))+o*p.dot(N.k)
print(p-q)
```

The result is:

```
(x(t))*N.i + (y(t))*N.j + (z(t))*N.k
```

But mathematically I would expect it to be the following:

```
x(t)-r*x(t)*sp.cos(w*t) + y(t)-r*y(t)*sp.sin(w*t) + z(t)*o*z(t)
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I overseeing something?

Comment: Explain the reasoning for your expected value.

Answer (score 0):

`q` is a scalar, not a vector-like quantity. The expression `p.dot(N.i)` gives the magnitude of `p` in the `i` direction but does not assign a direction. Try

```py
>>> q = r*(p.dot(N.i)*sp.cos(w*t)*N.i+p.dot(N.j)*sp.sin(w*t)*N.j)+o*p.dot(N.k)*N.k
>>> (p - q).dot(N.i) # look at i component of difference
-r*x(t)*cos(t*w) + x(t)
```

You might also look through the documentation about working with Vectors [here](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/vector/basics.html).